# How can I exclude large files while indexing?

Tags: indexing, solr, web-crawler

Is there a way to config Solr to ignore large files while indexing?

I'm trying to index a network drive but can't figure out how to ignore large files (>20MB).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try something of this nature:

$ find /mnt -type f -size -20M -exec /opt/solr/bin/post -c wizbang {} \;

If you use Tika, it has a file size limit though it is not 'ignore'ing the file:

[Apache Tika and character limit when parsing documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144708/apache-tika-and-character-limit-when-parsing-documents)

[How to read large files using TIka?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31079433/how-to-read-large-files-using-tika)